# What programming language was RStudio written in?

Tags: rstudio

What makes me curious is that when you right click anywhere on RStudio, it has the option "inspect element". I suspect it has to do with Javascript, but unsure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a mix. The user interface is indeed based on web technology and is written primarily in Java, using [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) to transpile to JavaScript; the back end is mostly C++.

The source is [hosted on GitHub](http://www.github.com/rstudio/rstudio), where you can see auto-generated language stats:

[image]